# Making the WebDriver wait without a ExpectedCondition

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Java / Selenium WebDriver / Firefox

> There is a text 'Input' field on a page. Then there is a 'Submit' button below it.
>   Both the input field as well as the Submit button are already enabled when the page is loaded.
>   After entering text in the input field, is there a way to make the WebDriver wait for 'x' seconds before clicking on Submit button,  instead of clicking it right away.
>
> > The option I can see is Thread.sleep(x) which I understand is not an efficient way. 
> >     The other option is using new WebDriverWait(driver,'x') without the Expected Conditions (as there is no Expected condition here as the Submit button is already visible and clickable). In this context, is this the same as using Thread.sleep(x)?
> >     Is there any other option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium [waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) designed to wait for specific condition. `Implicit wait` is waiting for the element to exist in the DOM in `driver.findElement()` and `explicit wait` is waiting for the `ExpectedCondition` to be `true`.

However, as soon as the conditions are met the code will continue or, if the condition failed, an exception will be thrown.

You can make the code "sleep" without thread by using some manipulation

```
WebDriverWait tempWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); // define local/temp wait only for the "sleep"
try {
    tempWait.until(ExpectedCondition); // condition you are certain won't be true
}
catch (TimeoutException) {
    continue; // catch the exception and continue the code
}
// continue the code
```

That will cause the code to simulate "sleep" for 10 seconds (the code won't continue, but `tempWait.until` will check repeatedly if the `ExpectedCondition` was met).

This is dirty work around and even less efficient than `Thread.sleep()`. If the purpose is to wait for some time regardless the web condition I recommend you use `Thread.sleep()`.